# LeftJoin in Laravel 5.5 including another table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, select, laravel-5

So i was working around with LeftJoin but i can't do it how i want it.

What i have:

```
Table 1: Blog_Category
Contains: `category_id`, `name`
Table 2: Blog
Contains: `blog_id`, `category_id`, `title` .... etc.
```

What i build, but isn't working:

```
public static function ShowAll() {
     return self::leftJoin('Blog', 'Blog_Category.category_id', '=', 'Blog.title')
        ->selectRaw('Blog_Category.*, count(Blog.blog_id) as Counts')
        ->groupBy('Blog_Category.category_id')
        ->get();
}
```

What i want to get is `category_id`, `name`, COUNT(count the blog_id which contain the current `category_id`)

In one word, i want to get the category count next to the name.
Thank you!

EDIT: Actually i just realized, that i don't need Join at all. I need to make this SQL into function:

```
SELECT blog_category.category_id AS id,
    blog_category.name AS name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blog WHERE blog.category_id = blog_category.category_id) AS count
    FROM blog_category;
```

Comment: Are you using Eloquent or the Query Builder?

Comment: i'm really not sure. This function is in Model class with: protected $table = 'blog_category';

Comment: Actually i don't need Join, read the post edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did it with the most easiest way, with raw Select.

I'm posting the code here, for those who had the same problem:

```
public static function ShowAll() {
    return self::selectRaw('blog_category.category_id AS id, blog_category.name AS name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blog WHERE blog.category_id = blog_category.category_id) AS count')->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent and make a model for blogs and blog category and then you can do $category = $blog->category